# When pausing a layer in cocos2d menu doesn't respond?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I was trying to create a gameover screen. It would create a new layer and place it on top of the current game layer and have a menu which would allow you to go home. But the menu doesn't respond after I pause all actions, any way around this? Thanks!

```
 //Pause all actions
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

    //Create new black layer
    CCLayerColor *gameover = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 75)];
    [self addChild:gameover z:1];

    //add menu
    CCMenuItemFont *item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Continue" target:self selector:@selector(goToMainMenu)];
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1, nil];
    [gameover addChild:menu z:110];
```

EDIT: I am trying to create a transparent layer on top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476199/is-there-anyway-to-have-a-the-menu-work-even-when-i-pause-the-game Take a look here

Comment: Shoot, thanks. I don't know why I didn't find that with all my earlier searches.

Comment: Well upon trying this, Do I need to create a whole new class with a scene? Not just a layer like above?

Comment: Sweet I win a question I didn't answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pausing the shared director pauses everything... I just asked this yesterday:

[Is there anyway to have a the menu work even when I pause the game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476199/is-there-anyway-to-have-a-the-menu-work-even-when-i-pause-the-game)

You can do what the guy did and also another method I found which was just inactivating all your scheduled selectors (i.e. `[self unschedule:@selector(gameLogicLoop:)];`)

And then you can reschedule the stuff after you are done clicking the menu (`[self schedule:@selector(gameLogicLoop:)];`).

Comment: Yes, sorry someone pointed your post out. The only thing is I need to create a whole new scene right? Not just create a layer like I did above?

Comment: My answer shows both ways to do it.  You can do a whole new layer, or you can just add the menu to self, or you can add the menu to a CCLayerColor, or almost anything you want.

Comment: or just go: [self unscheduleAllSelectors];

Answer (score 1):

I just wrapped everything in a BOOL and it worked fine for me.

```
BOOL paused;

-(void)goToMainMenu
{
    if (paused == YES)
    {
         [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainMenu scene]];
    }
}

-(void)gameOver
{
    paused = YES;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]];
}

-(id) init
{
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
       paused = NO;
       [self gameOver];
    }
    return self;
}
```

EDIT:

Why are you adding the CCMenu to the CCLayerColor? Just add it to the CCLayer.

```
[self addChild:menu];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)MenuStatus:(BOOL)_enable Node:(id)_node
{
    for (id result in ((CCNode *)_node).children) {
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[CCMenu class]]) {
            for (id result1 in ((CCMenu *)result).children) {
                if ([result1 isKindOfClass:[CCMenuItem class]]) {
                    ((CCMenuItem *)result1).isEnabled = _enable;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            [self MenuStatus:_enable Node:result];
    }
}
```

and then Call like

```
[self MenuStatus:YES Node:self]; //YES to Enable or NO to Disable the layer specified
```

Comment: Add a new layer after PAUSING the game. I had the same problem.  I just did like that and worked. The code sequence matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background3.png"];
    //[background initWithFile:@"background3.png"];
    [background setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];
    [self addChild:background z:1];
    [background setOpacity:420];
```

To make it FadeIn, this should work:

```
 CCLayerColor _shadowLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor: ccc4(0,0,0, 0)];
[_shadowLayer setContentSize: CGSizeMake(_winSize.width, _winSize.height)];

_shadowLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f); 
_shadowLayer.position = ccp(0, 0);

[self addChild: _shadowLayer];

[_shadowLayer runAction: [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1.5f opacity:100]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get what you want by the following approach

```
-(void) pause:(ccTime)dt
{
    NSLog(@"Pausing");
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    self.pausedTargets = [director.actionManager pauseAllRunningActions];
}

-(void) resume:(ccTime)dt
{
    NSLog(@"Resuming");
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director.actionManager resumeTargets:self.pausedTargets];
}
```